# Macro used in an external do-file in Stata

Tags: stata

My problem appears in a more general setting but can be illustrated with this example: the following lines create two new variables saving the estimates for a regressor using two different estimators

```
sysuse auto, clear 
reg price mpg, r
local m "reg"
gen bmpg_`m' = _b[mpg]
label var bmpg_`m' "`m' estimate"

areg price mpg, absorb(foreign) r
local  m "areg"
gen bmpg_`m' = _b[mpg]
label var bmpg_`m' "`m' estimate"
```

To save space and avoid repetitions, I created a external do-file, called `savest.do` which stores the following repeated two lines:

```
gen bmpg_`m' = _b[mpg]
label var bmpg_`m' "`m' estimate"
```

So, I get a shorter program:

```
sysuse auto, clear 
reg price mpg, r
local m "reg"
do savest

areg price mpg, absorb(foreign) r
local  m "areg"
do savest
```

However, this shorter program fails because it doesn't account for the macro `m` defined in a different external do-file. I used `global` instead of `local` but without success.

Comment: This is a better fit for StackOverflow or Statalist since there's no statistical content here. This is purely programming (but with a nice reproducible example).

Comment: Thanks. Right, I am always puzzled by the question: where should I post my questions :-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to write a little program that takes the name as an argument:

```
capture program drop savest
program define savest
syntax namelist(min=1 max=1)
    gen bmpg_`namelist' = _b[mpg]
    label var bmpg_`namelist' "`namelist' estimate"
end 

sysuse auto, clear 
reg price mpg, r
savest reg

areg price mpg, absorb(foreign) r
savest areg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass arguments to do-files:

```
* savest_1.do 
args m 
gen bmpg_`m' = _b[mpg]
label var bmpg_`m' "`m' estimate"

* savest_2.do 
local m `1' 
gen bmpg_`m' = _b[mpg]
label var bmpg_`m' "`m' estimate"

reg price mpg, r
do savest_1 reg
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Good to know but Dimitriy's solution is simpler when using more estimators and saving more estimates.

Comment: Indeed, but that was not what you asked.

Comment: I mentioned that my problem was more general than the illustration but yes I should have added that I wanted to use more estimators. Anyway, your answer was instructive and up-voted. Thanks also for editing my question.

Comment: @emeryville Glad the thread was resolved to your satisfaction.